# Need an OOP Trick

Tags: c#, oop

I want an abstract class that raises an event, this event will be raised by the concrete class.

What I want is when I use another class to listen to these events the signature of the delegate should have the concrete type not the abstract, I don't want to cast it.

For the moment I have come up with this solution. It works but I don't find it particularly clever especially because of the "STUPID, DOESN'T MAKE SENSE......" part.

Here is my solution :

```
public delegate void ClassAEventHandler<TClassA>(TClassA classA) where TClassA : ClassA;

//Abstract class that raise Event
public abstract class ClassA<TClassA> : where TClassA : ClassA
{
    public event ClassAEventHandler<TClassA> onClassEventRaised;    
    private TClassA eventClassA;

    public void registerEventClass(TClassA classA)
    {
        this.eventClassA = classA;
    }

    public void raiseClassEvent()
    {
        this.onClassEventRaised(this.eventClassA);
    }
}

// Exemple of concrete type
public class ClassB : ClassA<ClassB> // <------ IT SEEMS DUMB
{
    public void action()
    {
        //Do something then raise event
        this.raiseClassEvent();
    }

    public void saySomething() {};
}

// Exemple of concrete type
public class ClassC : ClassA<ClassC> // <------ IT SEEMS DUMB
{
    public void command()
    {
        //Do something then raise event
        this.raiseClassEvent();
    }

    public void destroySomething() {};
}

//Class that listen to the event raised
public class MyEventListener
{
    private ClassB classB;
    private ClassC classC;

    public MyEventListener()
    {
        this.classB = new ClassB();
        this.classB.registerEventClass(this.classB); // <------ STUPID, DOESN'T MAKE SENSE......
        this.classB.onClassEventRaised += classB_onClassEventRaised;

        this.classC = new ClassC();
        this.classC.registerEventClass(this.classC); // <------ STUPID, DOESN'T MAKE SENSE......
        this.classC.onClassEventRaised += classC_onClassEventRaised;
    }

    public void classB_onClassEventRaised(ClassB classB)
    {
        classB.saySomething();
    }

    public void classC_onClassEventRaised(ClassC classC)
    {
        classC.destroySomething();
    }

    //What i don't want
    /*
    public void classB_onClassEventRaised(ClassA classA)
    {
        ((classB)classA).saySomething();
    }   
    */
}
```

Comment: Not clear what problem you are trying to solve here. You've already narrowed the scope to a parent "abstract class that raise an event", but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not following regular event design in .NET.

Instead of implementing your own delegate, use `EventHandler<TArgs>`, and create a derived class of `EventArgs`.

Your `CustomEventArgs` should have a `T` generic parameter:

```
public class CustomEventArgs<T> where T : A
{
     private readonly T _instance;

     public CustomEventArgs(T instance)
     {
          _instance = instance;
     }

     public T Instance { get { return _instance; } }
}
```

Also, don't implement a custom way of registering events. If you want to encapsulate how handlers are added to the event, you need to use *event accessors*.

Finally, you could implement your classes as follows:

```
public class A<T> where T : A
{
     private event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs<T>> _someEvent;

     // An event accessor acts like the event but it can't be used
     // to raise the event itself. It's just an accessor like an special
     // event-oriented property (get/set)
     public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs<T>> SomeEvent
     {
          add { _someEvent += value; }
          remove { _someEvent -= value; }
     }

     protected virtual void RaiseSomeEvent(CustomEventArgs<T> args)
     {
           // If C# >= 6
           _someEvent?.Invoke(this, args);

           // Or in C# < 6
           // if(_someEvent != null) _someEvent(this, args);
     }
}


public class B : A<B> 
{ 
      public void DoStuff()
      {
           // It's just about raising the event accessing the whole
           // protected method and give an instance of CustomEventArgs<B> 
           // passing current instance (i.e. this) to CustomEventArgs<T>
           // constructor.
           RaiseSomeEvent(new CustomEventArgs<B>(this));
      }
}
```

Now, if you try to handle `SomeEvent`, you'll get the `CustomEventArgs<B>` typed as `B` instead of `A`:

```
B b = new B();
b.SomeEvent += (sender, args) =>
{
    // args.Instance is B
    B instance = args.Instance;
};
b.DoStuff(); // Raises SomeEvent internally
```

Comment: Thank you ! Its what i was trying to do (in the wrong way obviously)